# Input value from a DateTime Boostrap From

Tags: laravel

I try to get the value from the Datetime Boostrap, but it seems that it doesn't work.  Someone have an idea?  Where am I doing wrong?  By the way, the column `dt_rencontre` is a Datetime type in my database.

Here my view with the form :

```
<div class="input-group date form_datetime">
     <div class="input-group-addon">
           <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
      </div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control pull-right" value="13/06/2017 14:30">
</div>
```

Here my controller who should get the value :

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $rencontre = new Rencontre;

        $rencontre->dt_rencontre = $request->input('value');
```

...

Answer (score 1):

You missed the `name` attribute in input tag

```
<input type="text" name="datetime" class="form-control pull-right" value="13/06/2017 14:30">
```

and in your controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $rencontre = new Rencontre;

        $rencontre->dt_rencontre = $request->get('datetime');

        ....
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer ! it's working but when i want to store to the database i get : Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '15 Juin 2017 - 13:30'

Comment: MySQL retrieves and displays DATETIME values in 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' format. Use `Carbon` library to format your datetime.

Comment: i tried this :  $rencontre->dt_rencontre = $request->input(Carbon::parse('datetime')->format('Y-m-d h:m:s'));  but i get : DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (datetime) at position 0 (d): The timezone could not be found in the database

Comment: Try `$rencontre->dt_rencontre = Carbon::parse(Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i')->toDateTimeString());`

Comment: Missing argument 2 for Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat(), called in

Comment: `$rencontre->dt_rencontre = Carbon::parse(Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i',$request->get('datetime'))->toDateTimeString());`

Comment: it's working ! now if i would like the timezone France/ Paris how can i achieve that ?

Comment: `$rencontre->dt_rencontre = Carbon::parse(Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i',$request->get('datetime'))->toDateTimeString(),'France/Paris');` Refer this for more info http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

Comment: yes thanks ! i tried to store the date but i get : Unexpected data found.
The separation symbol could not be found
Unexpected data found. at Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i', '14 Juin 2017 - 13:25') in RencontreController.php line 55

Comment: `'14 Juin 2017 - 13:25'` should be `14/06/2017 13:25`.

Comment: the mistake come from my form ?

Comment: when i do a dd of $request->input('datetime') i get 13 Juin 2017 - 14:30

Comment: Your `$request->get('datetime')` should give you `14/06/2017 13:25.`

Comment: i make me this when i change the date and the hour on the calendar

Comment: Then use this `$rencontre->dt_rencontre = Carbon::parse(Carbon::createFromFormat('d M Y -  H:i',$request->get('datetime'))->toDateTimeString(),'France/‌​Paris');`

Comment: A textual month could not be found .at Carbon::createFromFormat('d M Y - H:i', '04 Avril 2017 - 16:52') . the problem come from the Month !